# Text changed event fired when control loaded, need to prevent on load?

Tags: wpf, textbox

In I have created a control that has a text box and a text changed event handler attached to it - this is in xaml.

The problem: when control is loaded the text changed event is fired, I do not want it to happen when the control is loaded only when I make actually make it change on the control by typing something.

What do you pros suggest I do? :)

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do is check the textbox's IsLoaded property inside the event handler before handling it.

Answer (score 0):

Attach Your EventHandler after the `InitializeComponent` Method in your constructor not in the `Xaml`.

i.e.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.TextChanged+=new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
}
```

---

I noticed that you are talking about an usercontrol, the only thing I can think of off the top of my head is to to create a property that can be used to inhibit the TextChanged Event until the Parent Form finishes loading. See if something like this works.

MainForm Xaml:

```
<my:UserControl1 setInhibit="True"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,103,0,0" x:Name="userControl11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="55" Width="149" setText="Hello" />
```

MainForm CS

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    userControl11.setInhibit = false;
}
```

UserControl:

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
}

public string setText
{
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
    set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
public bool setInhibit { get; set; }
void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (setInhibit) return;
    // Do your work here
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it is still fired. I think the reason for this is that I am binding to the textbox so it will always change.

Comment: thanks for your help. the only thing is that it has to always check the if statement

Comment: @user1622488 I think that above is the cleanist way, but if you wanted you could attach the eventhandler with the setInhibit Property. The problem is that you have two constructors, your form which is creating the usercontrol and your usercontrols and you are trying to inhibit the usercontrol, that is why you need to do it with something external.

Answer (score 0):

UserControl1.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

where TextChanged is the original event for TextBox

UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        _isFirstTime = true;
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event TextChangedEventHandler TextBoxTextChanged;
    bool _isFirstTime;

    //MyText Dependency Property
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBoxTextChanged != null)
            if (!_isFirstTime)
            {
                TextBoxTextChanged(sender, e);
            }
        _isFirstTime = false;
    }
}
```

where TextBox_TextChanged is the customized eventHandler for original TextChanged
and TextBoxTextChanged is more like a wrapper for the original TextChanged

Window.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <c:UserControl1 TextBoxTextChanged="TextBoxValueChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

as you see you can add an eventHandler to the event wrapper (TextBoxTextChanged)

Window.xaml.cs:

```
private void TextBoxValueChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("asd");
}
```

finally TextBoxValueChanged won't be fired the first time Text is changed

Answer (score 0):

```
private void TextBoxValueChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Textbox1.IsFocused)
        {
            App.Current.Properties["TextChanged"] = "1"; // Set Flag
        }            
    }

private void TextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
       if (App.Current.Properties["TextChanged"] == "1")
        {
            // Do Your Wor Here
            App.Current.Properties["TextChanged"] = "0"; // Clear Flag
        }
    }
```

On your XAML:

```
<TextBox xName="TextBox1" LostFocus="TextBoxLostFocus" TextChanged="TextBoxValueChanged"/>
```

(This is a very rudimentary, dirty, codebehind hack... checking the IsLoaded property as stated by Brent I found to be efficient)

Here since on textbox control creation it's not focused,  the TextChanged event will fire but the flag "1" is NOT set...
Later when user leaves field after editing it, since it had focus the Flag is set...  the LostFocus is fired, but only runnig code if textbox was changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of preventing this behavior across multiple inputs without having to create a unique bool for each input...

```
private void TextChanged_UpdateItem(object sender, TextChangedEventArg e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (!txtBox.IsFocused)
        return;

    //The rest of your code here
    
}
```

So basically, if the text field doesn't have focus (like on initialization) it just returns. This also prevents it from firing if the data is changed elsewhere. :)

**Alternatively**, as mentioned by Brent, you can just look for "IsLoaded":

```
private void TextChanged_UpdateItem(object sender, TextChangedEventArg e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (!txtBox.IsLoaded)
        return;

    //The rest of your code here
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brent's suggestion of using IsLoaded pointed me towards the right direction.

Because my UserControl's textbox is binded to a previous UserControl, the TextChanged event still gets fired because it changed from empty to the starting value even if I have the IsLoaded check <- which is not what I wanted; I wanted it to start detecting changes after everything is loaded and ready.

I created a flag in my VM to indicate whether the UserControl with the textbox is already opened. This way it will only start to detect text changes when textbox IsLoaded AND the UserControl is opened.

```
    private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = DataContext as myViewModel;
        if (myTextBox.IsLoaded && viewModel.userControlIsOpened)
        {
            viewModel.saveButtonIsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```